# Is 'both' appropriate in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, determiners

> Both *Government of India* and *State Governments* are working in tandem
>   to make subsidies in electric vehicle segment available.

My doubt is that 'both' phrase is used to convey two things!

But, in the above sentence even though there are two things, one is Government of India and the other is State Governments, since *State Governments* is plural, I feel there are more than 'two' things. So, *both* is wrong here!

Is 'both' appropriate in this sentence?

Comment: I think it is correct, the two subjects are 1) the central Government of India and 2) the local State Governments.

Comment: You mean you can't use "Both you and your parents should come"? Do you have to bring only one of your parents when you see this sentence?

Answer (score 3):

It's a very common error that occurs because of a tendency to use *both* everytime there are two parties involved, whether the word *both* is required and appropriate in the context or not.

In this case, *both* clashes with *in tandem* -- how can they work in tandem without both being involved? See the definition of *in tandem*.

Compare: "They both got married" -- this may in fact mean that the two persons got married but **not** to each other.

On the other hand, *governments* being plural is not relevant here. The central government on the one hand and the state governments on the other are working in tandem, so it's fine in that sense.